# Stripe Metadata submission invalid object

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe payments, but am unable to submit metadata as a query param as per the documentation, it seems as though it wants iterable stringified key-value pairs which I have tried to achieve with the below with no luck.

**Question: How can I pass metadata to Stripe using Dart and the HTTP library?**

```
class StripeServices {
  static var client = http.Client();
  static var stripeTestKey =
      'privatesecretkeyfromstripe';

  static Future<void> createStripeCustomer() async {
    Map<String, String> metadata = {'uuid': '123456'};
    Uri uri = Uri(
        scheme: 'https',
        host: 'api.stripe.com',
        path: '/v1/customers',
        queryParameters: {
          'description': 'Test Customer',
          'metadata': metadata.entries.toList().toString()
        });
    var response = await client.post(
      uri,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + stripeTestKey,
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
  }
```

The error I am getting back from the endpoint is

```
> flutter: {   "error": {
>     "message": "Invalid object",
>     "param": "metadata",
>     "type": "invalid_request_error"   } }
```

Answer (score -3):

calling Stripe API requires a secret API key, and you shouldn't store and use the API key in your frontend application because it's not safe.

Instead you should make the API call from your backend where the API key can be securely stored.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't even attempt to answer the question.